# Netlify + Cactus: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1

Tags: django, netlify

Im following this guide on how to deploy a django app using cactus on netlify:

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/04/08/a-step-by-step-guide-cactus-on-netlify/#building-your-site

I created a new private github repo and pushed the cactus stuff to it as per the docs.

However, when I try to deploy it on netlify, I get this error:

```
12:31:56 PM: [feature enabled]: Nitro deploys enabled. Buckle up! ⚡️
12:31:56 PM: Build ready to start
12:32:03 PM: build-image version: blablabla
12:32:03 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.6
12:32:03 PM: buildbot version: blablabla
12:32:03 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
12:32:04 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
12:32:04 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
12:32:04 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
12:32:04 PM: git clone https://github.com/blablabla/blablabla
12:32:05 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
12:32:05 PM: Starting build script
12:32:05 PM: Installing dependencies
12:32:06 PM: v10.19.0 is already installed.
12:32:07 PM: Now using node v10.19.0 (npm v6.13.4)
12:32:07 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
12:32:08 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
12:32:08 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
12:32:08 PM: Installing pip dependencies
12:32:08 PM: Started restoring cached pip cache
12:32:09 PM: Finished restoring cached pip cache
12:32:09 PM: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
12:32:09 PM: Collecting boto==2.49.0
12:32:09 PM:   Downloading boto-2.49.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
12:32:10 PM: Collecting cactus==3.3.3
12:32:10 PM:   Downloading Cactus-3.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (313 kB)
12:32:10 PM: Requirement already satisfied: certifi==2019.11.28 in /opt/buildhome/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2019.11.28)
12:32:10 PM: Collecting colorama==0.4.3
12:32:10 PM:   Downloading colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
12:32:10 PM: Collecting colorlog==4.1.0
12:32:10 PM:   Downloading colorlog-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
12:32:10 PM: Collecting django==1.6.11
12:32:10 PM:   Downloading Django-1.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.7 MB)
12:32:11 PM: Collecting django-markwhat==1.6.2
12:32:11 PM:   Downloading django_markwhat-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
12:32:12 PM: Collecting keyring==5.7.1
12:32:12 PM:   Downloading keyring-5.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
12:32:12 PM: Collecting markdown2==2.3.8
12:32:12 PM:   Downloading markdown2-2.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
12:32:12 PM: Requirement already satisfied: six==1.14.0 in /opt/buildhome/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (1.14.0)
12:32:12 PM: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tornado==6.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (from versions: 0.2, 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4.1, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1b2, 4.1, 4.2b1, 4.2, 4.2.1, 4.3b1, 4.3b2, 4.3, 4.4b1, 4.4, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.4.3, 4.5b1, 4.5b2, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.5.3, 5.0a1, 5.0b1, 5.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.1b1, 5.1, 5.1.1)
12:32:12 PM: ERROR: No matching distribution found for tornado==6.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
12:32:12 PM: Error installing pip dependencies
12:32:12 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
12:32:12 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:32:12 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
12:32:12 PM: Finished processing build request in 9.467329843s
```

---

I havent changed anything inside the cactus directory.

Also, I am using a virtual environment with python 3.7, and not python 2.7.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same challenges.
From the error log

12:32:09 PM: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

That means the deploy is done with Python 2.7, and tornado 6.0.4 was installed during cactus dependencies installation, which is not compatible with Python 2.7.

You could downgrade tornado to 5.1.1 by using $ pip install tornado==5.1.1

I hope this helped.